# Distinguish multi and single tenancy

Tags: single-page-application, multi-tenant, generalization

I am having a hard time distinguishing multi and single tenancy.

Like I know that having for example 10 publications/sites/domains on one site (like some sort of CMS) is multi-tenancy. I will provide an example. Lets say that I was given task that is to distinguish user (after login) that is served to me from DB. Thing is that this user can have different statuses imagine like status SILVER GOLD and PLATINUM and for each of these statuses slightly different UI should be displayed. Also it should be written in SPA (Single Page Application)

So my question is: would this example be considered multi-tenancy ? or single-tenancy ?
Why ? and could you dumb it down for me as much as possible please ?

Any kind of help will be higly appreciated !

Comment: Tenancy refers to how many customers the software serves. Would you consider silver/gold/platinum to be separate customers?

Comment: @Evan Trimboli yes, they are separate customers